# CS0501 error in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#

So I have been coding C# for a few days, making a Roblox Exploit. I am making a drop down menu for my exploit, using timer ticks and it says "CS0501  C# must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial". I am a newbie at C# so I searched the problem up and I am not able to figure out why this problem is occurring. The code is down below. Please help, and if so, put down the code so I can just see what was my problem! Thanks!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using WeAreDevs_API;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public void LuaTimer_Tick(EventArgs e, object sender);


    private ExploitAPI wolfapi = new ExploitAPI();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        wolfapi.LaunchExploit();
    }

    private void buttonKill_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string target = usernameTarget.Text;
        wolfapi.DoKill(target);
    }

    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string target = usernameTarget.Text;
        int speedValue = Int32.Parse(SpeedValue.Text);
        wolfapi.SetWalkSpeed(target, speedValue);
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string target = usernameTarget.Text;
        wolfapi.TeleportMyCharacterTo(target);
    }

    private void speedValue_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void updateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        wolfapi.IsUpdated();
    }

    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string script = luaExecutor.Text;
        wolfapi.SendLimitedLuaScript(script);
    }

    private void luaC_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string script = luaExecutor.Text;
        wolfapi.SendScript(script);
    }

    private void noDoors_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void luaExecutor_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void luaPanel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void luaOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void LuaTimer_Tick_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

Comment: What do you think this line - `public void LuaTimer_Tick(EventArgs e, object sender);` is *doing*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well,

```
 public void LuaTimer_Tick(EventArgs e, object sender);
```

is a method *without body*, so you should either *implement* it:

```
 public void LuaTimer_Tick(EventArgs e, object sender) {
   //TODO: put relevant code here
 }
```

or, technically, you can mark it as `abstract` (do not forget to mark *class* with `abstract` as well: `public abstract partial class Form1 : Form {...}`)

```
 public abstract void LuaTimer_Tick(EventArgs e, object sender);
```

Comment: I was wondering what a body was. I thought it was { } but I couldn't really figure it out. Well, okay then, it worked.

Comment: @Huskie: `public void LuaTimer_Tick(EventArgs e, object sender)` is a declaration, `{...}` - body